# python - Float values

Tags: python, floating-point

I have function where I am checking a value from a list with a float:

```
             A = 0.00001

             if (array [0] / array[1] < A) :
                      #do something 


              # array is a list with float64 type values and A's type is float
```

Will it create any problem in comparing?
and When I try to print the value of A, it shows as 1e-05. Why is that so?? I am new to python. Can anyone explain me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it create any problem in comparing?

If `a[1]` is equal to zero, or if `a[0] / a[1]` is larger than the largest representable number, or smaller than the smallest representable number, then you may have a problem.

The comparison itself is well-defined and means pretty much exactly what you think it does.

> When I try to print the value of A, it shows as 1e-05. Why is that so?

That depends upon how you try to print the value of `A`. Consider these ways of printing `A`:

```
In [1]: A = 0.00001

In [2]: print A
1e-05

In [3]: print '%f'%A
0.000010

In [4]: print '%e'%A
1.000000e-05

In [5]: print '%g'%A
1e-05
```

As you can see, each way of printing `A` prints a different text representation of A. But just as `10`, `ten` and `0xA` all represent the same number (the number of fingers on my hands), each of these results represent the same number (the number you get when divide 1 into 100,000 parts).

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a problem.  `A` prints as `1e-05` by default because when numbers are very small or very large it is more compact to display them using [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).